# Is there a way to write this code in recursive form?

Tags: c++, loops, vector

This function checks if elements of vector a are in vector b or not. They should be in contiguous form.

```
bool i_vec(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)
{
    for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i <= b.size() - a.size(); i++)
    {
        if(equal(a.begin(), a.end(), &b[i]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My recursive way. Is this correct?

```
    vector<int>::iterator pos;

    pos = search(b.begin(),b.end(),a.begin(),a.end());
    if (pos != b.end())
    {
        cout << "true" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    cout << "false" << endl;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Its a loop, so the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Just about *any* iterative algorithm can be converted to a recursive one, the question you *should* be asking is: is it a good idea?

For, example, a function to add unsigned numbers:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a + b
```

can be made recursive with:

```
def add(a,b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    return add(a-1,b+1)
```

However, that's a *horrible* idea and you're likely to run out of stack space pretty quickly for the expression:

```
c = add(9999999999,4)
```

For your specific case when you have two sorted vectors, you can quite easily do a similar thing, finding the first common element then using recursion to advance each list index concurrently. Something like, once you've found the common element:

```
def contains(a,idxa,b,idxb):
    if idxa >= a.size or idxb >= b.size:
        return true
    if a[idxa] != b[idxb]:
        return false
    return contains(a,idxa+1,b,idxb+1)
```

But you have the same problem as with `add` above. For a large enough list, you'll exhaust stack space before you get a result.

The "better" way to check it is to, like the resursive solution, find the first common element, but *then* simply advance the indexes concurrently in a loop. This is both more readable and less prone to the restrictions imposed by recursion.